# VB.net XOR operation using HEX

Tags: vb.net, hex

I want to calculate a BCC XOR in hex using Visual Basic 2012 for the following String: H enter * in hex (48 0D 2A) using the following rule: 
`Step 1. BCCXOR = 00h` BCCXOR = 00
`Step 2. BCCXOR = BCCXOR xor 48` BCCXOR xor first character - result BCCXOR = 48h
`Step 3. BCCXOR = BCCXOR xor 0D` BCCXOR xor second character - result BCCXOR = 44h
`Step 4. BCCXOR = BCCXOR xor 2A` BCCXOR xor third character - result BCCXOR = 6Fh

My code is:

```
    Dim BCCXOR As Integer = &H0
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.TextLength - 1
        BCCXOR = (BCCXOR) Xor Conversion.Hex(Strings.Asc(TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, i + 1).ToString()))
    Next
    BCCXOR = BCCXOR Xor Hex(&HD)
    BCCXOR = BCCXOR Xor Hex(&H2A)
    TextBox2.Text = BCCXOR
```

My problem is that I receive an error message when I'm trying to calculate BCCXOR xor 0D I receive an error like: 
Conversion from string "D" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Comment: I managed to calculate the in DEC and convert the result to HEX. Please help me to mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hex fonction converts a number to a string. I don't think this is what you want. Just remove the fonction call and it should work.

```
BCCXOR = BCCXOR Xor &HD
BCCXOR = BCCXOR Xor &H2A
```